# How to configure Kafka environment from different frameworks of Js and Go to ship JSON

Tags: javascript, go, logging, apache-kafka, microservices

I am building a couple of micro-services and a logging micro-service along with it.

The logging micro-service code will come after the other micro-services have sent their logs to kafka. Logging as a micro-service has to consume all the log data which is sent from  JS-based micro-services and I have to receive the JSON in GO.
Is there any other way without using a parser? (Just like  g-RPC changes the whole data to binary for faster transportation and is understandable for every environment.)

I have very less knowledge about how the different environments work together when using a message broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking.

Kafka stores bytes, and there's clients in both JS or Golang. Both languages/environments need to have available libraries for serialization and deserialization. Regarding golang, you don't need a struct to read JSON.

> like g-RPC changes the whole data to binary for faster transportation and is understandable for every environment

You can use Protobuf in Kafka topics.

---

Alternatively, you can use tools like Elasticsearch or Splunk to consume any Kafka event and index the fields after deserializing those records without needing any Go consumer.

But yes, a parser will be needed somewhere to index your data into a searchable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [schemas (Protobuf, Avro, JSON Schema)](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html), so it will be converted to binary, although to utilize its full benefits, you will need a [schema registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html) otherwise, it will embed schema to every message.

Comment: I don't think native Protobuf binary includes schemas in every event

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is, as it has no other options without schema registry

Comment: That's not true. You can use Protobuf binary encoding directly without any external components. The consumer will need to have its own copy of the schema or compiled model. The only benefit of the registry is that the schema is centralized. Besides, question was asking about plain json, which definitely doesn't have a schema